# Rotate starting point of svg animation

Tags: css, animation, svg

So I'm trying to understand svg animations.

For some reason my rotation of the starting point won't work.
See following animation.
I want to start the animation-line from the other side.
Following [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31775990/svg-animation-start-position) I found that I need to use rotation.
But if I use that it doesn't show up.What am I missing?

So I added `transform="rotate(180)"` to the path of the line.
NOTE: I didn't add rotate to the current snippet.

```css
body {
 background: #85d1d3; 
}
.container{
 max-width:400px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

@keyframes line-color-ffffff { 0% {fill: #85d1d3;}  50% {fill: #85d1d3; stroke-dashoffset: 0;} 100% {fill: #85d1d3;stroke-dashoffset: 0;} }

.line-color-ffffff{animation: line-color-ffffff 4s ease forwards; stroke-dasharray: 20; stroke-dashoffset: 199;}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 800 800">
   <title>svg</title>
   <g id="background">
    <rect width="400" height="400" fill="#85d1d3"/>
   </g>
  <g>
  <path class="line-color-ffffff" d="M471.954 512.869 467.207 510.091 464.528 508.522 406.469 474.539 401.11 471.402 396.364 468.624 401.085 465.803 403.354 464.447 439.663 442.751 444.201 440.039 448.923 437.218 444.159 434.468 441.628 433.007 415.474 417.907 410.412 414.984 405.649 412.234" fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="3"/>
  </g>
  </svg>
```

Comment: so you would like that animation to start from the top and not the bottom?

Comment: The animation now goes from right bottom to left top. I want that to change from left top to right bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its actually pretty simple too solve, just switch out the 0% fill with the 100% ones!

```
@keyframes line-color-ffffff {  0% {fill: #85d1d3;stroke-dashoffset: 0;}    50% {fill: #85d1d3; stroke-dashoffset: 0;}  100%{fill: #85d1d3;}   }
```

Here is a working fiddle aswell: https://jsfiddle.net/g6Lpcmqe/

Comment: Amazingly simple. Thank you!

Comment: *You're ;-) Here's a potato.

Comment: Woops my grammar sucks:)